# Cabeçalho e rodapé padrão para todas páginas

Tags: php, html, include

No site que estou fazendo, assim como a maioria, o header e footer da página nunca mudam, apenas o conteúdo do body. Com header e footer me refiro à toda a parte que fica além do `<body></body>`.

O que estou fazendo é colocar os seguintes códigos:

header.php (simplificado)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Título</title>
        <!-- Aqui também incluo scripts de css e js -->
    </head>
    <body>
```

footer.php (simplificado)

```
    <!-- Incluo mais alguns scripts -->
    </body>
</html>
```

index.php (simplificado)

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    <h1>Página</h1>
    <!-- Conteúdo -->
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

No começo até que era muito funcional, não precisava repetir códigos. Ficava um pouco confuso, principalmente na organização do HTML, mas funcionava. O problema é agora que o projeto está grande demais. Tem muitos scripts que só devem serem carregados em determinadas páginas, não sendo necessário carregá-los em todas (incluindo-o no header.php ou footer.php). Não gostaria de colocar no final do body de cada página, pois não poderia controlar a ordem de carregamento (muito importante quando se usa js). Se alguém conhece alguma forma de contornar ou resolver o problema por biblioteca, etc. por favor ajude.

PS: Sei que existe o Composer. Não aprendi a usá-lo ainda, mas acredito que ele não consegue incluir header e footer, e caso consiga, provavelmente não posso escolher quais scripts serão carregados em cada página (meus scripts).

Comment: Para evitar longas discussões nos comentários a conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132682/discussion-on-question-by-pedro-henrique-cabecalho-e-rodape-padrao-para-todas-pa). Quem quiser ler ou acrescentar algo, pode utilizar o link fornecido.